# How to take snapshot in libVLC without showing the Media Player

Tags: c++, libvlc

I am trying to take snapshot from VLC player using libVLC. But whenever I run the following code, a window opens showing the video streaming and I don't want to open the media player window while doing that. I am taking the video input from an IP camera using RTSP link. Is there a way where I can achieve my goal by keeping the media player window hidden?

Here is my code that I've done till now.

```
    m = libvlc_media_new_location(inst, "IP/camera/rtsp/link");
    mp = libvlc_media_player_new_from_media(m);
    libvlc_media_player_play(mp);
    while (1) {
        Sleep(500);
        const char* image_path = "E:\\frames\\image.jpg";
        int result = libvlc_video_take_snapshot(mp, 0, image_path, 0, 0);
    }

    libvlc_media_player_stop(mp);
    libvlc_media_player_release(mp);
    libvlc_release(inst);
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank for your question. Add

```
 const char* const vlc_args[] = {
            "--intf", "dummy",                 
           "--vout", "dummy",                 

    };
```

when creating libvlc new inst and pass it as argument.